# Merge two assemblies at runtime - C#

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies

Is it possible to merge two assemblies at runtime such that, when you iterate over the ExportedTypes, all the types from both original assemblies are returned?

The why:

I use a database migration framework to update my databases.  It take a single assembly made up of special classes which defines the modifications made to the database.

I have two databases the are very similar.  Many tables are identical, but each has a couple of unique tables.  I would like to have a general migration assembly and a specific assembly for each database.  But to use it with my framework, I need to stuff the two assemblies into a single one.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en):

> ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly.

Though it only runs in the v2.0 .NET runtime.

Comment: I think you beat me by almost a minute, so I'm going to remove my identical answer and upvote yours.